# Connect to MSSQL from Blazor Server app on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, asp.net-core, ado.net, blazor

We're developing a .NET Core Blazor server app that will ultimately be hosted on a Linux box and which must connect to Microsoft SQL Server instance running on a Windows host elsewhere on our network.  The application is simple and just needs to read data from database tables.

In a prototype project we've included a reference to the System.Data namespace and have used OLEDB to successfully connect to and read from the database.  However, when the prototype is moved onto a Linux host we get a PlatformNotSupportedException, "System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform".

After perusing the web we're more confused than ever.  Can someone recommend a connection strategy from a .NET Core app running on a Linux host that needs to connect to Microsoft SQL Server?

We naively thought .Net Core would solve this type of cross-platform issue and would appreciate guidance from someone who has resolved this design issue.  We can be flexible and use OLEDB, ODBC, native SQL client, etc to connect but would like to be able to use ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone recommend a connection strategy from a .NET Core app running on a Linux host that needs to connect to Microsoft SQL Server?

You can try to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` that provides the data provider for  Microsoft SQL Server.

https://github.com/dotnet/sqlclient

Comment: Thanks for that. I’ll download Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and give that a go.

Comment: Fei, we've replaced System.Data.OleDB in our prototype code with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and have successfully connected to the database and read a table.  We now need to move the prototype onto a Linux server to ensure we've got the cross-platform independence we're looking for.

Comment: Fei, thanks for your help.  Our prototype code with the reference to  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is working as we need it to on Linux.  Cheers